# Change return type of OPTIONAL MATCH to array, if nothing was found

Tags: neo4j

*I am trying to figure out, how to deal with null values of an* `OPTIONAL MATCH` *result. I would like to return an empty array instead of* `null`*.*

Returns the users as list, regardless of the number of users:

```
MATCH(u:User {some_property: "some_value"})
RETURN properties(u) LIMIT 25
```

Returns the users as list, if the number of users > 1, otherwise `null`:

```
MATCH(u:User {some_property: "some_value"}), (x:SomeLabel {id: "<<someID>>"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:SOME_RELATION]-(x) 
RETURN properties(u) LIMIT 25
```

Returns the users as a **nested** list (array in an array), if the number of users > 1, otherwise as list.

```
MATCH(u:User {some_property: "some_value"}), (x:SomeLabel {id: "<<someID>>"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:SOME_RELATION]-(x) 
RETURN COLLECT(properties(u)) LIMIT 25
```

What is an elegant way to always return a list, neither nested nor `null`? Using conditional expressions only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting that syntax from, `RETURN as ...` isn't valid, and even if it were, `properties()` returns a map, not a list. Also in your last query, `COLLECT(properties(u))` should return an empty list even if `u` is null, so you shouldn't need to force the return of an empty list.

But for some other query where you want to return an empty collection instead of a null, you can use `COALESCE()` to return a default value you provide if the first expression is null.

```
...
RETURN coalesce(possibleNullVariable, []) as result
```

Comment: My fault, I edited the query. `COALESCE(properties(u), [])` works just fine, thanks!

Comment: A slightly different example: How can I ensure that `CALL apoc.index.search("IndexName", "My Query~") YIELD node WITH COLLECT(node) as node RETURN COALESCE(node, []) ` always returns a list?

Comment: It always will, no need for COALESCE there. When you're using COLLECT() on a null or nonexistent value, it will result in an empty list automatically.

Comment: But I made the test. If it does find an entry, it is nesting the resulting list in another array.

Comment: I'm not seeing that. I see a list of property maps. I think you may want to read up on the differences between [lists](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/) and [maps](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/). Otherwise, if I'm misunderstanding something, please provide an example.

Comment: The query `CALL apoc.index.search("User", "Ja~") YIELD node WITH COLLECT(properties(node)) as u RETURN u SKIP 0 limit 25` RETURNS a array of arrays: `_fields:  [ [ {  "name": "Jan" ...`. You can see that it is a nested array. The query `MATCH(u:User) RETURN properties(u)` RETURNS a array of objects: `_fields:  [ {  "name": "Jan" ...`. In both queries, it matches the same node.

Comment: That's plumbing around the returned data, disregard that, it's not relevant when we speak of the type of data returned. Try `RETURN "foo"` and you'll see that `_fields` still places this in brackets. It's not useful when we speak of return types. `COLLECT(properties(node))` is returning a collection of map properties. `properties(u)` is a map of properties.